# How to setup reCaptcha to appear on the registration form?

Tags: 8, captcha

[reCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) is ported to Drupal 8. I've set up captcha and recaptcha. I've read Readme.txt from recaptcha, I've registered my site and got the API key and paste it, also I've looked at Readme.md from captcha module.

But it does not appear in the user registration form.

All I can see is this [image]

So please, what to do? Where should I set up captcha appears on regform?

Comment: Check whether you can place math captcha in user register page.

Comment: If choose Math on this page the situation does not change - I also cannot find where should I place the captcha field. If I switch on "Add captcha administration links to forms" it appears on forms I do not need. But to look it on regform is impossible: admin cannot visit regform!

Comment: Click captcha points tab and check captcha enabled for user registration form. If not enable it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `CAPTCHA Points` tab, you need to click on the enable button.

[image]