# reCaptcha get the code & use in custom module

Tags: 8, captcha

[How to setup reCaptcha to appear on the registration form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213195/how-to-setup-recaptcha-to-appear-on-the-registration-form)

I followed above link & able to setup reCaptcha for Login form. It works fine.

Now for login I'm creating my custom Multi-Step form. 4-5 steps.

How we can define where to show this captcha or which code needs to be use so we can show it whenever it requires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will add the captcha,

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
...
  $form['captcha'] = array (
    '#type' => 'captcha',
    '#captcha_type' => 'recaptcha/reCAPTCHA'
  );
  return $form;
}
```